# Returning a value from addEventListener

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a need to retrieve data from an external API. The data returned is in JSON format, and I can read it just fine. The problem is, I am calling a function which then goes and gets a username. I then want to return that username back to the calling function, but no matter what I try, I always get an "undefined" value.

If I display the username in the console prior to the RETURN, I can see the value without issue, but the return of the variable does not seem to work.

There is more code to this, but this is the part that I simply cannot seem to get right (please note I have left comments in the code too):

```js
var myName = '';
myName = GetSender(mySenderID); // this is called from another JS function, mySenderID does have a value
console.log(myName); // show "undefined"

function GetSender(SenderID)
{

    var data = JSON.stringify(false);
    var mySenderName = "";

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.withCredentials = false;

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
        if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
    
            response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            mySenderName = response.user.first_name + " " + response.user.last_name;
            console.log(mySenderName); // this shows a value
            return mySenderName; // This part does not return anything to the calling function
            
            }
    });

        xhr.open("GET", "https://blah.com/" + SenderID);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Public-Token", "78fc204914f6a1231a34c456ff487fa6");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json; version=1");
        xhr.send(data);

}
```

Comment: You have to ask "who is going to call the event listener"?  The answer is probably not your code at all, but the framework/library you are using.  You can write `debugger;` right before `return mySenderName;` and step through the code to see where it returns to.

Comment: at the time your `console.log` is executing `GetSender` hasn't finished executing yet. This is because of asynchronous evaluation. sjahan's link should help you

Comment: @jmb.mage - I added debugger as per your suggestion, and when mousing over the variable name in the return line, it has the correct value.

Comment: @dgeare - what link??